# How do you detect when a file is changed in iCloud?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, icloud

When a file is changed in iCloud (whether added, deleted, or the content changed), I would like to call a method I created (`[self methodName]`) so that I can update my table view with the names of the new files. How am I notified of the file change? Do I need to listen for a NSNotification (if so, what is it?) or do I have to check manually? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the NSNotification I have to listen for is `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`. This is how I did it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidUpdate:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:query];

...

-(void)queryDidUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //something changed, reload (NSMetadataQuery, create NSPredicate, rerun the query, etc.)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This section of the Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) contains a great tutorial for setting up document-based iCloud apps.

To answer your questions, though: as long as your document is a `UIDocument` you can register for a notification.  Just search that page for "Monitoring Document-State Changes and Handling Errors" - there is tons of source code to help you out.

Comment: Ok, there's my problem. I'm using NSFileManager to manually move things to and from my iCloud container, not UIDocument. I'll have to look into that. Thanks.